# Entity Framework Code First table relationships

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, database-design, entity-framework-6

I have a C# app which connects to a Web API which feeds my app some XML data for estate agency listings and agents.

The XML looks something along these lines:

```
<Snapshot>
      <Agents>
        <Agent id="838388" firstName="John" surname="Smith"/>
        <Agent id="838389" firstName="Jane" surname="Doe"/>
        <Agent id="838390" firstName="Mary" surname="Appleton"/>
        <Agent id="838391" firstName="Peter" surname="Gill"/>
      </Agents>

      <Listings>
        <Listing id="1737672" officeId="801948" agencyName="Century 21">
          <Agents>
            <AgentRef id="838388" />
            <AgentRef id="838391" />
          </Agents>
        </Listing>

        <Listing id="1737673" officeId="801949" agencyName="Remax">
          <Agents>
            <AgentRef id="838390" />
            <AgentRef id="838389" />
          </Agents>
        </Listing>
      </Listings>
    </Snapshot>
```

I have decided to use using Entity Framework 6.2, code-first approach. So I created these two classes:

```
public class Agent
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        public int AgentId { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string Surname { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Listing> Listings { get; set; }
    }
```

and

```
public class Listing
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        public int ListingId { get; set; }
        public int OfficeId { get; set; }
        public int AgencyName { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Agent> Agents { get; set; }
    }
```

As you can see, it's a many-to-many relationship between Agents and Listings. So one Agent can have zero or more listings associated to him, and one listing can have zero or more agents associated to it.

So, my app reads all the agents in the first  tag, and inserts all the agents into the agents table. Then, later, when it reads all the listings, it looks like EF is trying to create those agents again. Obviously, this gives a PRIMARY KEY violation error, as it's trying to add a second agent again with the same ID.

I am using XDocument to parse the XML. This is the bit where I read the AgentRef elements of the listing:

```
XElement root =  xDoc.Root.Elements("Listings").Descendants("Listing");
if (root.Descendants("Agents").Any())
{
    List<string> agentRefs = root.Element("Agents").Elements("AgentRef")
    .Select(a => a.Attribute("id").Value).ToList();
    listing.AgentRefs = agentRefs.Select(int.Parse).ToList();
}
```

Any ideas how I can tackle this?

Comment: Please include the relevant code that processes the listings. Also specify if you use one and the same `DbContext` instance for inserting agents and listings.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Ivan. I am using only one DbContext. Basically, my XML parsing routine returns a "Snapshot" class which has a collection of Agents and a collection of Listings. I then loop through the Agents and Listings collections, adding each item to the dbContext, and right at the end I call dbContext.SaveChanges();

Comment: In my Listing class above, I am tempted to replace:

*public virtual ICollection<Agent> Agents { get; set; }*

with

*public virtual ICollection<int> AgentRefs { get; set; }*

to better reflect the XML. But this wouldn't create the navigational properties EF requires to do it's job properly and create the Listings-Agents bridging table, would it?

Comment: I did also post it here - maybe I've explained it slightly better?
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8391bfc3-1e1c-4bf9-afe2-d6bfbfe4f638/entity-framework-trying-to-add-navigational-children-of-parent-class-twice?forum=adodotnetentityframework

Comment: No, the entity model is ok, just the code (not shown) that applies the changes most likely is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

If the agent already exists in the DB you must EF tell that by attaching the agent to the context:

```
using(var myContext = new MyContext)
{
   var agent = new Agent() { AgentId = 838388 };
   myContext.Agents.Attach(agent);

   var listing = new Listing() { ... };
   listing.Agents.Add(agent);

   myContext.Listings.AddObject(listing);

   myContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Duy. I now get this :)

Attaching an entity of type 'Agent' failed because another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value. This can happen when using the 'Attach' method or setting the state of an entity to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' if any entities in the graph have conflicting key values. This may be because some entities are new and have not yet received database-generated key values. In this case use the 'Add' method or the 'Added' entity state to track the graph and then set the state of non-new entities to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' as appropriate.

Comment: I did also post it here... maybe I've explained it slightly better?
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8391bfc3-1e1c-4bf9-afe2-d6bfbfe4f638/entity-framework-trying-to-add-navigational-children-of-parent-class-twice?forum=adodotnetentityframework